# Cloud Storage showing requests per second even when not used

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

I have recently setup a Google Cloud Storage Bucket, used the api to put some stuff in, get some stuff out!  For the last few days I haven't touched it, and no one else has access to it, yet the Requests screen is showing that I have made over 6,000 requests and on the chart it's saying 0.08 Requests per second!

Anyone know why this might be the case?

mARK

Answer (score 1):

If you're curious as to whether or how your Google Cloud Storage buckets are being accessed, you can enable access logs on a bucket to get exact metrics. This process is documented here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs#delivery

You can set this up using the command line utility, gsutil, like so:

```
$> gsutil mb gs://my_logs_bucket
$> gsutil acl ch -g cloud-storage-analytics@google.com:W gs://my_logs_bucket
$> gsutil defacl set project-private gs://my_logs_bucket
$> gsutil logging set on -b gs://my_logs_bucket gs://bucket_i_care_about
```